# What is the equation for average compound atomic mass?

Tags: average, applications, chemistry

I am facing a mathematical problem in chemistry:
Suppose we have two atoms X and Y , each has two isotopes (forms of the same atom with different masses)

(X1) mass = 12 (units) and represents 90% of the X atom forms in nature (its abundance in nature)

(X2) mass = 11 (units) and represents 10% of the X atom forms in nature (its abundance in nature)

(Y1) mass = 3 (units) and represents  85% of the X atom forms in nature (its abundance in nature)

(Y2) mass = 4 (units) and represents  10% of the X atom forms in nature (its abundance in nature)

So, average mass for X atom = [(X1 mass * X amount in nature * X1 abundance) + (X2 mass * X amount in nature * X2 abundance)] / (X amount in nature)
, and Y the same way

Now if we have a compound that contains 3 atoms of X bound to 2 atoms of Y, then what will be the average mass of the compound? It is expressed in Chemistry books as : 3*average mass of X + 2*Average mass of Y

What is the prove that yield the last equation ?

Comment: Basically, $\dfrac {a+b}{c+d} \ne \dfrac ac + \dfrac bd$.

Comment: Of course , but is the compound average mass equal the sum of average masses of atoms forming it ?

Comment: Yes. That is why the "amounts of atoms in nature" values should not be mixed between different atoms.

Comment: I think: average mass of compound (XY) =( mass of  X in nature + mass of Y in nature) /number of XY coumpounds that can be formed by them